# AWS Athena ODBC with ADFS & MFA

Tags: amazon-web-services, odbc, amazon-athena

We are trying to use the Simba ODBC driver to connect from local windows machine to AWS Athena.
Works fine with IAM Credentials but struggling with ADFS - simply getting a 'SAML assertion not found' message.

In the AD logs, it shows that I was successful there.
We do have MFA set up for our AWS environment - and I assume that that requirement is not getting satisfied by the driver - there is no way to enter a code.
I have found no mention of MFA in the driver documentation, so can only assume that it has no facility to handle ?

Has anyone else used these drivers with MFA ?
I know that Microsoft have published drivers capable of working with MFA, and find it hard to comprehend that AWS have not !?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is going to help you much but here it is how I solved it for JDBC https://github.com/ahtokca/athena-adfs-mfa-plugin